# Which encryption is this?

Tags: encryption, base64, crypt

pt this - `MFpRMg==` , which encryption is this ? I am sure that is a symmetric encryption.
I tried base64 but it wasn't worked, also I tried AES

Comment: This could really be anything. It all just depends how you interpret these few characters (e.g. is it a one-time pad encrypted message?). You have to analyze the context, i.e. who produded that message, what algorithms could possibly be used etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, since ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. We're not here to play the [guessing game](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but you can guess yourself: [determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/45523)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the last two characters are "==", the length is a multiple of 4 bytes and the bytes are ASCII it is probably a Base64 encoding.

`MFpRMg==` Base 64 decodes to hex `30 5a 51 32` or in ASCII: `0ZQ2`. Since that looks like ASCII and not random bytes (which encrypted looks like) and it is shorter than usual encryption block lengths `0ZQ2` is probably the answer.

Notes:

For symmetric encryption a key is required in order to decrypt a message, none is given. Without the key the only options is to try all possible keys and be able to recognize the correctly result. This is really not generally possible.

Most symmetric encryption is block based with common block lengths of 8 or 16 bytes. Thus the output is a multiple of the block size with the exception of using a streaming mode.